# Clave morse en un array con numpy

Tags: python, array, numpy, jupyter

Buen día, quiero realizar un convertidor de castellano a clave morse mediante el uso de un diccionario usando la librería Numpy de Python para ellos he hecho lo siguiente:

Cree lo que seria el diccionario a trabajar, en este caso la clase morse:

```
cod = {
'A': '.-',     'B': '-...',    'C': '-.-.',
'D': '-..',    'E': '.',       'F': '..-.',
'G': '--.',    'H': '....',    'I': '..',
'J': '.---',   'K': '-.-',     'L': '.-..',
'M': '--',     'N': '-.',      'O': '---',
'P': '.--.',   'Q': '--.-',    'R': '.-.',
'S': '...',    'T': '-',       'U': '..-',
'V': '...-',   'W': '.--',     'X': '-..-',
'Y': '-.--',   'Z': '--..',    '1': '.----',
'2': '..---',  '3': '...--',   '4': '....-',
'5': '.....',  '6': '-....',   '7': '--...',
'8': '---..',  '9': '----.',   '0': '-----',
'.': '.-.-.-', ',': '--..--',  ':': '---...',
';': '-.-.-.', '?': '..--..',  '!': '-.-.--',
'"': '.-..-.', "'": '.----.',  '+': '.-.-.',
'-': '-....-', '/': '-..-.',   '=': '-...-',
'_': '..--.-', '$': '...-..-', '@': '.--.-.',
'&': '.-...',  '(': '-.--.',   ')': '-.--.-'}
```

Lo siguiente que hice fue agregar ese diccionario a un array usando numpy:

```
import numpy as np
alfa = np.array(cod)
alfa
array({'A': '.-', 'B': '-...', 'C': '-.-.', 'D': '-..', 'E': '.', 'F': '..-.', 'G': '--.', 'H': '....', 'I': '..', 'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-', 'L': '.-..', 'M': '--', 'N': '-.', 'O': '---', 'P': '.--.', 'Q': '--.-', 'R': '.-.', 'S': '...', 'T': '-', 'U': '..-', 'V': '...-', 'W': '.--', 'X': '-..-', 'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..', '1': '.----', '2': '..---', '3': '...--', '4': '....-', '5': '.....', '6': '-....', '7': '--...', '8': '---..', '9': '----.', '0': '-----', '.': '.-.-.-', ',': '--..--', ':': '---...', ';': '-.-.-.', '?': '..--..', '!': '-.-.--', '"': '.-..-.', "'": '.----.', '+': '.-.-.', '-': '-....-', '/': '-..-.', '=': '-...-', '_': '..--.-', '$': '...-..-', '@': '.--.-.', '&': '.-...', '(': '-.--.', ')': '-.--.-'},
  dtype=object)
```

Acontinuacion lo que hice fue generar un input para escribir la palabra que deseo cambiar:

```
palabra = input("Palabra:")
```

Y a esto le cree un ciclo for:

```
Lcodigos = []
for car in palabra:
if car.islower():
    car=car.upper()
Lcodigos.append(alfa[car])
print (" ".join(Lcodigos))
```

A esto al ejecutar el for me genera el siguiente error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-e36117ebc449> in <module>
  2     if car.islower():
  3         car=car.upper()
----> 4     Lcodigos.append(alfa[car])
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

¡Agradezco cualquier ayuda!.

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: no puedes usar una letra como índice; tiene que ser un entero ... Además, ¿para qué usas numpy cuando el diccionario `cod` tiene todo lo que necesitas?

Comment: Hola @CandidMoe pues la idea es implementar numpy en lo que seria ese ejercicio lo unico que se me ocurrio fue usarla en un array, algun consejo?

Comment: `alfa` es un arreglo de 1x1, o sea que tienes un "arreglo" que sólo contiene un elemento. Ese elemento es el diccionario `cod`. Reemplaza `alfa` por `cod` y tu programa funcionara.

Comment: @CandidMoe agradezco la ayuda, sin embargo lo que quiero hacer es que dentro de alguna aparte del código utilice numpy.

Comment: Como te comenta @CandidMoe no tiene sentido usar una librería, de **análisis númerico** `Numpy` cuando se puede hacer simplemente con un diccionario. No sé quien te a mandado este ejercicio, pero desde luego es malísimo para enseñar a utilizar `Numpy`. Es como si quieres realizar una ensalada con una sartén.